# JQM pagebeforeshow event called two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Having a very small example demonstrating my issue with jquerymobile: http://jsfiddle.net/forrest_gump/uuWLP/

As you can see in a console log:

`pagebeforeshow - pageIndex (index):45
onDeviceReady: function() (index):39
pagebeforeshow - pageIndex (index):45
onDeviceReady: function()`

pagebeforeshow happens two times and I spent a lot of time trying to find out why!?! Am I stupid or is it a jqm bug?

Comment: you are using `changePage()`, event is called twice, one time for first page and then when you change that page http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/

Comment: Yes, I use changePage() and if I understand correctly it should be called once for each page before showing. In my case I have set up a pagebeforeshow event for the first page only. Why it happens the second time?

Comment: My bad, you are correct, should only be fired one time as i read it too

Comment: Could be a fix, using navigate() instead of deprecated method changePage(): http://jsfiddle.net/kJhY8/  I'm sorry but i didn't know jquery mobile at all

Comment: @A.Wolff if he's using jQM 1.3, he can use `changePage` its deprecated on jQM 1.4

Comment: @Omar thx for relevant info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When first page is initiated and displayed, it is `data-url` is saved in `$.mobile.UrlHistory` as *base* URL without *hashtag*. For example, first page's URL is `www.stackoverflow.com/index.html`, other pages have page's ID *hashtag* `www.stackoverflow.com/index.html#pageLogin` and so one.

When you move to another page from *Homepage* with `changeHash` disabled, jQuery Mobile Navigation updates URL bar with `www.stackoverflow.com/index.html` not `www.stackoverflow.com/index.html#pageLogin`, hence, it triggers *page* events again.

If you still want to disable `changeHash` and avoid multiple evnets firing, you need to disable [`hashListeningEnabled`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/global-config/) once jQuery Mobile is initialized (`mobileinit` event).

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    });
  </script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dACzd/)**

Answer (score 0):

Firefox works fine for me. On webkit browsers try to remove `changeHash` option.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Why does `changeHash` "fix" the problem?